# gyronorm library: how to pass a sensor-value into a function properly?

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile, p5.js, gyroscope

everybody!

I am a total newbie in programming and i am pretty sure that how i'm doing this is a complete mess and utterly bad... i am an industrial design student and i am working on a project for my semesterproject. this is all just one weird and sloppily attempted experiment...

I am trying to build a gesture controlled synthesizer that runs in the browser on a mobile device, using the data from gyroscope and accelerometer. i am using the p5.js and p5.sound.js library together with the gyronorm.js library.

for the moment i managed to make the thing work as a monosynth that plays one note and i am trying to modulate the amplitude with the sensordata from the gyroscope. it works so far, turning the phone around the z-axis (lying flat on the table, face upwards), but it makes those strange crackling noises. i think it might have to do with the framerate of the draw function, but i have no idea whtas wrong, to be honest and i can'T really find answers in google, because i really don't quite exactly know, what i am looking for XD.

so here is my code:

```
let gn; // global variable for the Gyronorm Constructor
let movZ, movX, movY; //global variables for the accelerometer values

var alpha = 0,
  beta = 0,
  gamma = 0; //global variables for the gyroscope values

let vol; //global variable for the value calculation of the z-axis (alpha) value
let osc1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  frameRate(120);

  osc1 = new p5.Oscillator();
  osc1.freq(300);

  osc1.start();
  //constructor for gyroscope
  gn = new GyroNorm();

  let args = {
    decimalCount: 2,
    frequency: 10
  }

  gn.init(args).then(function() {
    gn.start(function(data) {
      // Process:
      alpha = data.do.alpha; //( deviceorientation event alpha value 0- 360 degrees)
      beta = data.do.beta; //( deviceorientation event beta value )
      gamma = data.do.gamma; //( deviceorientation event gamma value )


      movZ = data.dm.z; //( devicemotion event acceleration z value )
      movX = data.dm.x; //( devicemotion event acceleration x value )
      movY = data.dm.y; //( devicemotion event acceleration y value )
      vol = abs(sin(radians(alpha))); //trigonometric calculation of the alpha value to a value between 1 and 0

    });
  }).catch(function() {
    notAvailable()
  });
}


function draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);

  osc1.amp(vol);

  text("rotationZ (computed): " + vol, 200, 300);
  text("rotationX: " + beta, 200, 350);
  text("rotationY: " + gamma, 200, 400);

  text("accZ: " + movZ, 50, 300);
  text("accX: " + movX, 50, 350);
  text("accY: " + movY, 50, 400);

}

function notAvailable() {
  text("Gyroscope not supported!Sorry...", 300, 300);
}
```

and here is a link to the localtunnel, so you can try it on your phone (i think this should work?)

[http://4892fdea.ngrok.io](http://%20http://4892fdea.ngrok.io)

does anybody have an explanation or hint or anything??? i would really appreciate it! please help me, because i am really stuck here!thx

best regards!

Ludwig

Comment: It's hard to judge from the code you've provided. You said potentially it's a framerate issue, have you tried changing the framerate to see if it changes behaviour? By default it's set to 60, so maybe try add `frameRate(30);` in your `setup()`

Comment: thanks for your comment! well i tried that and it makes a difference, so far, that the crackling becomes clearer, louder and it appears in fewer steps, so to speak.